# When is countable direct product of projective modules again projective?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module, direct-product

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. The Bass-Papp theorem states that any countable direct sum of injective $R$-modules is injective iff $R$ is Noetherian . Chase's theorem states that any direct product of projective $R$-modules is projective iff $R$ is Artinian. My question is:

> Is any characterization for commutative rings (with unity) known such that any countable direct product of projective modules over the ring is again projective ?